# How to set the position of text message in alert dialog

Tags: android, position, android-alertdialog

How to set the position of text message in alert dialog?. I want it to be in the middle

Comment: I think for that you need to implement Custom Dialog .

Answer (score 1):

Use `AlertDialog.Builder` to build your alert dialog and call `setView(View view)` with the view containing your message placed in the center.